# Cannot search movies in Neo4j Movies sample application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

On Ubuntu 16.10 I have followed the instruction from:

https://github.com/neo4j-examples/movies-java-spring-data-neo4j-4

But when I go to http://localhost:8080/ and try to search for e.g. Matrix nothing happens, it just looks empty:

[image]

I have verified that the neo4j db has been populated with the required data and I also updated user/pass in the `.properties` file in the maven project.

Any ideas, and is it possible to find a log somewhere?

Pressing F12 in Firefox gives:

[image]

Indicating the error in the sources as described in the below answer, did not manage to get the same error info in Chrome when pressing F12 though.

Comment: The Chrome developer console is showing any error message?

Comment: The application may not have implemented case-insensitive searching? Try searching for "Matrix" or even "The Matrix"

Comment: Tried both and same result, both in Firefox and Chrome

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code in the GitHub project is not properly updated. The `MovieRepository.java` class has `findByTitleContaining` method and `@param` is missing in this method. If you check the `index.html` file, javascript code is executing  `/movies/search/findByTitleLike?title=*` URL. The quick fix will be add following method in `MovieRepository.java` and then execute `mvn spring-boot:run` command again.

```
Collection<Movie> findByTitleLike(@Param("title") String title);
```

In order to have proper source and test classes, you should replace `findByTitleContaining` method with `findByTitleLike` method in `MovieRepository.java` class and also fix the `MovieRepositoryTest.java` class to use the correct method. Delete `testFindByTitleContaining` method and add following method in `MovieRepositoryTest.java` class.

```
@Test
public void testFindByTitleLike() {
    String title = "Matrix";
    Collection<Movie> result = instance.findByTitleLike("*"+title+"*");
    assertNotNull(result);
    assertEquals(1, result.size());
}
```